# Out of gas transaction using delegatecall

Tags: solidity, gas, delegatecall

I'm currently trying to develop my knowledge further on lower level calls such as DELEGATECALL.

I am continiously running into when trying to use .delegatecall():

```
RunTime Error: out of gas
Gas Usage: 0xe07e44(Decimal = 14712388)
```

delegateCall contract:

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
 import "delegateReceiever.sol";

contract delegateCall{
uint public testInt;
address public sender;

function delegateCall(){
    testInt = 1;
}

function delegateCallC(address _c, uint _testInt){
if(_c.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("setTestInt(uint")),_testInt ))
throw;
}  
}
```

delegateReceiever contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
contract delegateReceiever{
uint public testInt;

function delegateReceiever(){
    testInt = 2;
}

function setTestInt(uint _testInt){
    testInt = _testInt;
}
}
```

Edited truffle deploy to increase gas like so:

```
deployer.deploy(contract,{gas:114712388})
```

Edited testrpc initial account balance to:

```
1e+167
```

Edited truffle.js file to include gas:

```
rpc:{
   host: "localhost",
   port: 8545,
   gas: 114712388
}
```

Is there any other method of ensuring gas will not run out? For example, is there a developer parameter that requires no gas etc..?

Comment: For my own learning, is `"setTestInt(uint"` missing a closing parentheses on purpose?

Answer (score 4):

`delegatecall` returns `true` on success, so

```
if(_c.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("setTestInt(uint")),_testInt ))
    throw
```

will throw if the call is successfull.

Try

```
if(!_c.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("setTestInt(uint")),_testInt ))
```